# Popup menu в action bar

Tags: android, activity, xamarin

Проблема в том, что `popup`, который я задаю в `action bar'e` не умещается на экране.
К тому же, я пишу не на чистом `android'e`, а на `xamarin android`, но не думаю что проблема в этом.

Итак вот код:

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu){
    Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits, WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.popup_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Использовал `SetFlags` так, как нашел похожую ситуацию [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38680567/popup-menu-goes-out-of-the-screen), но мне не помогло, или же я что-то неправильно делаю. К тому, что мне надо сделать в `action bar'e`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И это только на версиях андроида 4.2.
На 4.3. и 5.1 и 6.0 работает без нареканий.